# Laravel - retrieving mysql query result array returned to controller to display in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

How do I retrieve the result array returned from my model :-

```
$result = DB::select('select title from mainTable');
return $result;
```

in my controller so that I can pass it to my view :-

```
$title = "Main Page";
$data =             //I want to assign the result to data
$view = View::make('mainpage')->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to figure out how to add something to the $data variable and pass it into a View. If you assign something as

```
$data['result'] = DB::select('select title from mainTable');
return View::make('main page', $data);
```

You will now be able to access the query results as $result from within your blade template. I would definitely recommend using the ORM so that you can get the entire result in a single query, as in:

```
// Model /app/models/Main.php
class Main extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'mainTable';
}

// Controller (within route method)
    $data['result'] = Main::find(1);
    /* Gets the mainTable result with an id of 1 */

    return View::make('page', $data);

// Template /app/views/page.blade.php
    <h1>{{ $result->title }}</h1>
    <!-- Outputs the title for the result as an H1 HTML element -->
```

Comment: yes, u guessed it right at the beginning. As I was using codeigniter, I am trying to put all the db queries in the model and then pass it to the controller which will then pass it to the view

Comment: but I still don't have an answer to y Laravel is trying to make us run a query in the controller or fetching data from the database from the controller

Comment: Yeah, I switched from CI to Laravel as well. It took me a little bit to wrap my mind around the ORM (especially relationships), but once it clicks it saves a LOT of time!

Comment: If you set up a Model, Laravel will only run the query(ies) when you call the model. So when you call Model::find(1) it uses the ORM to execute "SELECT * FROM mainTable WHERE id = 1" (depending on your db) and then returns the result as an object with the value of each column accessible as $object->column. Then you just pass that off to your $data array as $data['result'] = $object, and when you pass that to the View all contents of the $data array are accessible as their key value, i.e. $result. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm sure you figured this out already, but all you have to do to create a model is create a file /app/models/Main.php with the content
   class Main extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'mainTable';
   }

Comment: ya I do get what u r saying. I'll try the above solution and check if its working

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a model like this

```
class Main extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'mainTable';
}
```

Then from your controller you can use following code to get all records from `mainTable` table:

```
$title = "Main Page";
$data = Main::get(array('title'))->toArray(); // Or Main::all(['title']);
return View::make('mainpage')->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

**Update:** You can use something like this if you want

```
class Main extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'mainTable';

    public function scopeGatAllByFieldName($q, $field = null)
    {
        if(is_null($field)) return $q;
        return $q->select([$field]);
    }
}
```

From your controller you may call it like:

```
$title = "Main Page";
$data = Main::gatAllByFieldName('title')->get()->toArray();
return View::make('mainpage')->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

Comment: but the only problem I have is that - shouldn't stuff like db queries, logic and all be in model...? Why is Laravel forcing the developer to put something like a db query in the controller

Comment: Laravel isn't forcing you to do anything.  If you want to further abstract the DB query then by all means go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel docs (http://laravel.com/docs) do a great job of demonstrating how to use the Database and Query Builder modules.

```
"The select method will always return an array of results." (http://laravel.com/docs/database.)

$data = DB::select('select title from mainTable');
$view = View::make('mainpage')->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

I much prefer using Query Builder.

```
$data = DB::table('mainTable')->select('title')->get();
$view = View::make('mainpage')->with('data', $data)->with('title', $title);
```

Comment: the problem i find here is that you have a db query in the controller. shouldn't it be in the model

Comment: You can create functions in your model to manipulate your database and then call them in you controller. In your case a function getTitle for exemple. And then Modelname::getTitle()->get()

Comment: @MrShibby I tried this but I get  an error "Call to a member function get() on a non-object"

Comment: What if you just call getTitle() ? Like $data = mainTable::GetTitle()?

Comment: hey $data = mainTable::GetTitle() worked , just that i had to remove another line $data = ['first' => 'pet1', 'second' => 'pet2'];